# jQuery: Select <a> which points to the current URL

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

In jQuery, how do you select the `<a>` which href is pointing to the current URL

For example:
URL = http://server/dir/script.aspx?id=1

I want to select this `<a>`
`<a href="/dir/script.aspx">...</a>`

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
var url = window.location.href;
$('#ulTopMenu a["'+url+'"*=href]').addClass("selected");
```

Probably wrong syntax. Anyone know the right way of doing it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Remy, it didn't really work but it's close.
Here is my final code

```
  var scriptname = GetUrlScriptname();
  $('#ulTopMenu a[href$="' + scriptname + '"]').parent().addClass('selected');

function GetUrlScriptname()
{
  var rex = new RegExp("\\/[^\\/]+\\.\\w+($|\\?)");
  var match = rex.exec(location.pathname);
  return match[0].substring(1);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you're trying to solve the selected tab 'pattern'. I've found I can solve this myself with the following code:

```
var nav = location.pathname.substr(1).split('/', 2)[0] || '/';
if (nav) {
    $('#ulTopMenu a[href$="' + nav + '"]').parent().addClass('selected');
}
```

This basically says add the class of selected if the URL ends with the same ending as the current URL.  Though you have to watch out for 'similar' urls - but if you have a lot of urls that are actually similar, you should probably consider a server side solution.

(I posted an article a while back on this technique - if it's actually what you're trying to do: http://leftlogic.com/lounge/articles/auto-selecting_navigation/)

Answer (score 1):

I do not know the answer to your question but is that selector syntax valid?

```
'#ulTopMenu a["http://www.foo.com"*=href]'
```

I'd imagine if such a thing is possible it'd be written as

```
'#ulTopMenu a[href*="http://www.foo.com"]'
```